# How can I improve the test coverage of MetadataService.cls (recent Version for API v35)?

Tags: apex, unit-test, metadata-api, code-coverage

I'm using the APEX wrapper for Metadata API found here https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Looking at the test coverage, there are a lot of lines uncovered. Can this be improved easily?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an issue report on github here https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/119

I've created the missing invocations to get the coverage close to 100%

Add this code (also in the github-issue) into your MetadataServiceTest.cls and you will be fine:

```
@IsTest
private static void elfMissingGetRecordsTest() { // elf patch
    new MetadataService.ReadFlowResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAssignmentRulesResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAssignmentRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAutoResponseRulesResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAutoResponseRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEscalationRulesResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEscalationRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadPostTemplateResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadApprovalProcessResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadHomePageComponentResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadHomePageLayoutResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomObjectTranslationResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadTranslationsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadProfileResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadPermissionSetResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadDataCategoryGroupResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadRemoteSiteSettingResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadPackageResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAuthProviderResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadKnowledgeSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingSetResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSecuritySettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadIdeasSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadChatterAnswersSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCommunityResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadActivitiesSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadContractSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadOrderSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadOpportunitySettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadProductSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadQuoteSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCallCenterResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEntitlementProcessResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMilestoneTypeResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEntitlementTemplateResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEntitlementSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadBusinessHoursSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadBusinessHoursEntryResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadConnectedAppResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAppMenuResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMobileSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadNetworkResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCompanySettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadForecastingSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSamlSsoConfigResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLiveAgentSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSkillResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLiveChatDeploymentResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLiveChatButtonResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLiveChatAgentConfigResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSynonymDictionaryResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadFolderResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadReportFolderResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadDashboardFolderResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadDocumentFolderResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEmailFolderResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadRoleOrTerritoryResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowActionResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSiteDotComResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowTaskResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowSendResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowOutboundMessageResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowKnowledgePublishResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowFieldUpdateResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWorkflowAlertResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadVisualizationPluginResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomMetadataResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadNameSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMarketingActionSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomPermissionResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAuraDefinitionBundleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCorsWhitelistOriginResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadManagedTopicsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadTerritory2Result().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadTerritory2ModelResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadTerritory2SettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadTerritory2TypeResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadXOrgHubResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadActionLinkGroupTemplateResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLicenseDefinitionResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMarketingResourceTypeResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMatchingRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMatchingRulesResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadNamedCredentialResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadPersonalJourneySettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingRulesResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingBaseRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingCriteriaRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingOwnerRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingTerritoryRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadMetadataWithContentResult().getRecords();

    new MetadataService.ReadCustomSiteResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadListViewResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadInstalledPackageResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomFieldResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadFieldSetResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadPicklistValueResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadRecordTypeResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadWebLinkResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAddressSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCaseSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomObjectResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLayoutResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadEmailTemplateResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadScontrolResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadApexPageResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadApexComponentResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadApexClassResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadApexTriggerResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadStaticResourceResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadDocumentResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomLabelsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomLabelResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAccountSettingsResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadQueueResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomDataTypeResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadExternalDataSourceResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadGroupResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadBusinessProcessResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCompactLayoutResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadSharingReasonResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadValidationRuleResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadReportTypeResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadReportResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadDashboardResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadAnalyticSnapshotResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomPageWebLinkResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadQuickActionResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadFlexiPageResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomTabResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomApplicationComponentResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadCustomApplicationResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadPortalResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadLetterheadResult().getRecords();

    new MetadataService.ReadFlowResult().getRecords();
    new MetadataService.ReadFlowResult().getRecords();



}

@IsTest
private static void elfMissingGetResultTest() { // elf patch
    new MetadataService.checkStatus_element();
    new MetadataService.checkStatusResponse_element();

    new MetadataService.readWorkflowRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSamlSsoConfigResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomLabelResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readBusinessHoursEntryResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMobileSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readChatterAnswersSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingRulesResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readPortalResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSkillResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEscalationRulesResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomDataTypeResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readExternalDataSourceResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEntitlementProcessResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readRecordTypeResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readScontrolResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readDataCategoryGroupResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readValidationRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readProfileResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readIdeasSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readConnectedAppResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readApexPageResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readProductSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLiveAgentSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readOpportunitySettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLiveChatDeploymentResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readActivitiesSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLayoutResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWebLinkResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSiteDotComResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCompanySettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readHomePageLayoutResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readDashboardResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAssignmentRulesResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAnalyticSnapshotResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEscalationRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomSiteResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readGroupResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readReportTypeResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readQuickActionResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomPageWebLinkResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readApexComponentResponse_element().getResult();
    // new MetadataService.readBaseSharingRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEntitlementTemplateResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readFlexiPageResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowActionResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAddressSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readContractSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomObjectResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readTranslationsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readRoleOrTerritoryResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readApexTriggerResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomLabelsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSecuritySettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCallCenterResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readPicklistValueResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readRemoteSiteSettingResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readQuoteSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSynonymDictionaryResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readPostTemplateResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomTabResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLetterheadResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readInstalledPackageResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readQueueResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAuthProviderResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEntitlementSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomFieldResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readStaticResourceResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEmailTemplateResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingReasonResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLiveChatButtonResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readNetworkResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readApprovalProcessResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMilestoneTypeResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAssignmentRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCompactLayoutResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLiveChatAgentConfigResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAccountSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readBusinessProcessResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readFlowResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAutoResponseRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readPermissionSetResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readBusinessHoursSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readForecastingSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readReportResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAppMenuResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readListViewResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readOrderSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomObjectTranslationResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomApplicationResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readKnowledgeSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCaseSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readApexClassResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readPackageResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCommunityResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readDocumentResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAutoResponseRulesResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readFolderResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomApplicationComponentResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readFieldSetResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingSetResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readHomePageComponentResponse_element().getResult();

    new MetadataService.readReportFolderResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readDashboardFolderResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readFlowResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readFlowResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readDocumentFolderResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readEmailFolderResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowTaskResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowSendResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowOutboundMessageResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowKnowledgePublishResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowFieldUpdateResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readWorkflowAlertResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readVisualizationPluginResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomMetadataResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readNameSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMarketingActionSettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCustomPermissionResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readAuraDefinitionBundleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readCorsWhitelistOriginResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readManagedTopicsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readTerritory2Response_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readTerritory2ModelResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readTerritory2SettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readTerritory2TypeResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readXOrgHubResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readActionLinkGroupTemplateResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readLicenseDefinitionResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMarketingResourceTypeResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMatchingRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMatchingRulesResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readNamedCredentialResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readPersonalJourneySettingsResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingBaseRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingCriteriaRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingOwnerRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readSharingTerritoryRuleResponse_element().getResult();
    new MetadataService.readMetadataWithContentResponse_element().getResult();


}
```